# PHP string variable in WHERE clause MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am having a problem with this simple sql query:

```
<?php 
require_once('../../Connections/tohoshows.php'); 

$show ='gothaf';

mysql_select_db($database_tohoshows, $tohoshows);
$query_getShows = "SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show =' ". $show. " '";
$getShows = mysql_query($query_getShows, $tohoshows) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getShows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getShows);
$totalRows_getShows = mysql_num_rows($getShows);

mysql_free_result($getShows);
?>
```

When I use the string directly in the WHERE clause like this

```
 $query_getShows = "SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show ='gothaf'";
```

I get a result. When I use the variable instead, I get no data! I am a novice and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you getting no date because you have extra space betwee the quotes,

```
$query_getShows = "SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show =' ". $show. " '";
                                                                    ^ HERE      ^
```

which will then be parsed into

```
SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show =' gothaf '
```

---

remove it and it will work

```
$query_getShows = "SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show ='". $show. "'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have also tried with no spaces in between, but I still get no data.

Comment: post the result of this  `echo $query_getShows;`

Comment: You shouldn't even consider using this approach anyway, @Akis, it's really easy to use prepared statements and yet it is system critical.

Comment: This what I get from the echo $query_getShows;

     `SELECT * FROM toho_shows WHERE toho_shows.show ='gothaf'`

though I still get no data when I test the SQL statement in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Is there anything in that table that matches that?

Comment: OK guys! This thing actually works, I don't know why dreamweaver doesn't return any data on the sql statement test! Thanks everybody! @Jonast92 I will consider the prepared statements as you said! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much,